# Network update in Linkedin API is not working anymore

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I used to get all the network updates of a logged user but now this API is not working and giving the response "Network Access denied".

What do I have to do to access this API again? Or is it totally eliminated from Linkedin REST API?

Comment: When was the last time it worked?  Have you reviewed the release notes for the API?

Comment: Recently.. cannot figure it out properly as still my app is in development mode..

Answer (score 1):

According to [their documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition);

> [...] take affect and will be rolled out to the entire LinkedIn application base **between May 12th - May 19th, 2015**.
>
> [...] Note that users with existing OAuth grants will have to **re-authenticate due to the change in requested permissions**.

Please take a look at their [May Transition FAQ](https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/transition-faq) which states a few things;

- OAuth 1.0a support is gone
- Tokens expire after 60 days (this is unchanged, but thought I'd note it)
- *The upcoming changes will not affect how any of the APIs work (with one exception noted in point #2 below), only whether you will be able to call them any longer.*

And you can find more resources [here](https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=c41cVdnYDuqq8wf-tQE#q=linkedin+api+update+2015+authentication)